# Bootcamp vs VM on MacBook 7,1

Tags: virtualbox, boot-camp, multi-boot

I have a MacBook which is less than a week old. I'm considering installing Windows on it for development purposes. I'm going to be using it for Flash development and VB development.

From a user perspective, I'm trying to figure out if I should virtualize or install in a separate partition. I'm concerned because my MacBook only has 2GB of memory, and a 250GB Hard Drive.

Which option do you advise for me? Why?

(Also, I have genuine disks for XP pro and Windows 7 Ultimate. Which one should I use?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want best performance I would go for Bootcamp. If you run a VM on your MacBook with only 2Gb of RAM everything is going to feel sluggish. So go for Bootcamp, an other alternative would be to upgrade your Macbook to 4Gb RAM and then run a VM on it.

Comment: How much HDD would you give Windows?

Comment: Somewhere between 50Gb to 80Gb should be okey.

Answer (score 0):

50GB is not enough IMHO, I had to re-isnstall and gave mine half the HD space, painful but necessary if your going to install a IDE like Visual Studio.